# Trying to change the text "Purchase Invoice" in LedgerTrans

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I need to change the text "Purchase Invoice something" in the LedgerTrans text generated for purchase invoices.

More specifically, the need is to shorten it because it is used in another system through an interface.

It is obvious that this text must be parametrized somewhere, but I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can find what you are looking for under `Basic` -> `Setup` -> `Transaction text` which opens a form like the one below. In that form you should find and change the text template for one of the 'Purchase xxx' records.

Hope that helps

[image: Transaction texts]

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the answer I was looking for. I could shorten the text. However in my environment, there is only one Language set, it is "user" – whereas elsewhere the Language is 'fr', 'de', and so on.